# Difference between: child::node() and child::*

Tags: xslt

I just wrote an XSLT that did not work at first.

I had to rename all children of `<Recordset>` to `<C>`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Record>
<Recordset>
    <company>102</company>
    <store>1801</store>
    ....
</Recordset>
<Recordset>
....
</Recordset>
</Record>
```

I used the following XSLT:

```
<xsl:template match="Record/Recordset/child::*">    
    <xsl:element name="C">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```

It works and renames all children of `<Recordset>` to `<C>`.
But first my match in the template looked like this:

```
<xsl:template match="Record/Recordset/child::node()">
```

My idea was that every child of `<Recordset>` is a node, thus `node()` would be appropriate.
It worked too but it inserted an extra `<C/>` for each child.

What's the difference between `child::node()` and `child::*`?

Comment: _"My idea was that every child of <Recordset> is a node"_ >> this statement is correct, but you forgot about the text node children, even though they are whitespace-only in your example. Other children that are not elements are also nodes: comments and processing instructions. Namespace nodes and attribute nodes are treated specially.

Comment: Thank you Abel for your comment. I have figured it out in the meantime.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

`child::node()` matches any node that's not an attribute node, namespace node, or document node. That means that it *does* match processing instructions, comments, and text nodes.

`child::*` matches *only* elements.

See [section 5.5.3](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#pattern-semantics) of the spec:

> The pattern node() matches all nodes
>   selected by the expression
>   root(.)//(child-or-top::node()), that
>   is, all element, text, comment, and
>   processing instruction nodes, whether
>   or not they have a parent. It does not
>   match attribute or namespace nodes
>   because the expression does not select
>   nodes using the attribute or namespace
>   axes. It does not match document nodes
>   because for backwards compatibility
>   reasons the child-or-top axis does not
>   match a document node.

**Update:** Michael's answer inspired the following stylesheet. Use it to test the types of nodes as they're processed:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="/|node()">
        <xsl:call-template name="type" />
        <xsl:text>  [  </xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="." />
        <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()" />
        <xsl:text>  ]  </xsl:text>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template name="type">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="count(.|/)=1">
                <xsl:text>Root</xsl:text>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="self::*">
                <xsl:text>Element </xsl:text>
                <xsl:value-of select="name()" />
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="self::text()">
                <xsl:text>Text</xsl:text>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="self::comment()">
                <xsl:text>Comment</xsl:text>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="self::processing-instruction()">
                <xsl:text>PI</xsl:text>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="count(.|../@*)=count(../@*)">
                <xsl:text>Attribute</xsl:text>
            </xsl:when>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Modify what's matched/selected to test other patterns. For example, the following input:

```
<A attr="test" other="val">
  <B/>
  <C>some value</C>
  <!-- a comment -->
  <D/>
</A>
```

Produces the following output:

```
Root  [  

  some value



Element A  [  

  some value



Text  [  

  ]  Element B  [  
  ]  Text  [  

  ]  Element C  [  some value
Text  [  some value
  ]    ]  Text  [  

  ]  Comment  [   a comment 
  ]  Text  [  

  ]  Element D  [  
  ]  Text  [  

  ]    ]    ]
```

Special thanks to [this page](http://www.dpawson.co.uk/xsl/sect2/nodetest.html#d7653e255) for getting me started on the node-type tests. (It's especially fitting that one of Michael's answers from over six years ago appears there, too.)

Comment: Thank you very much for the node-test example! I have always been a bit confused about text, node and element...

Answer (score 20):

To expand on lwburk's answer, if your XML looks like this:

```
<A>
  <B/>
  <C/>
  <D/>
</A>
```

Then the A element has 7 child nodes; three of them are elements, four are text nodes. The expression `child::node()` matches all 7, whereas `child::*` only matches the elements.

Comment: Thank you Michael. I will have to play around with that too. I don't "see" the 4 text nodes yet.

Comment: After every `">"` and before the next `"<"` there is some whitespace. There are four such gaps, and each one is a whitespace-only text node.

Comment: Hello Michael, Thank you - I didn't know about the whitespaces being text nodes. Now I get it and now I also get my original problem with the extra <C>-elements that were inserted. Thank you very much!