# Difference between * and node() in XSLT

Tags: templates, xslt, matching

What's the difference between these two templates?

```
<xsl:template match="node()">

<xsl:template match="*">
```

Comment: This answer is also applicable : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5394178/difference-between-childnode-and-child

Answer (score 44, accepted):

```
<xsl:template match="node()">
```

is an abbreviation for:

```
<xsl:template match="child::node()">
```

**This matches any node type that can be selected via `the child::` axis**:

- element
- text-node
- processing-instruction (PI) node
- comment node.

**On the other side**:

```
<xsl:template match="*">
```

is an abbreviation for:

```
<xsl:template match="child::*">
```

**This matches any element**.

The XPath expression: someAxis::* matches any node of the primary node-type for the given axis.

For the `child::` axis the primary node-type is *element*.

Answer (score 17):

Just to illustrate one of the differences, viz that `*` doesn't match `text`:

Given xml:

```
<A>
    Text1
    <B/>
    Text2
</A>
```

Matching on `node()`

```
<xsl:stylesheet
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

    <!--Suppress unmatched text-->
    <xsl:template match="text()" />

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <root>
            <xsl:apply-templates />
        </root>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="node()">
        <node>
            <xsl:copy />
        </node>
        <xsl:apply-templates />
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Gives:

```
<root>
    <node>
        <A />
    </node>
    <node>
        Text1
    </node>
    <node>
        <B />
    </node>
    <node>
        Text2
    </node>
</root>
```

Whereas matching on `*`:

```
<xsl:template match="*">
    <star>
        <xsl:copy />
    </star>
    <xsl:apply-templates />
</xsl:template>
```

Doesn't match the text nodes.

```
<root>
  <star>
    <A />
  </star>
  <star>
    <B />
  </star>
</root>
```

Comment: Nor does `*` match comment nodes, processing instruction nodes, attribute nodes, namespace nodes and document nodes... The pattern or expression `*` (on its own, as abbr. for `child::*`) **only ever matches element nodes and element nodes only**. When using `@*`, short for `attribute::*`, the asterisk matches _only_ attribute nodes on the attribute axis.

Answer (score 2):

Also refer to [XSL xsl:template match="/"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127108/xsl-xsltemplate-match)
for other match patterns.