# Check type of node in XSL template

Tags: xslt, xpath-1.0

Is it possible to check the type of a node I matched with a template inside the same template? In case it is, how can I do it? For example I would like to do something like this:

```
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="current() is an attribute">
        <!-- ... -->
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="current() is an element">
        <!-- ... -->
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
        <!-- ... -->
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Tim has given a nice answer but I wonder why you need to do this inside the template and why you do not just write more specific match patterns with separate templates for the different node types.

Comment: I am interested in it for educational purposes. I am building an XSL transformation to highlight nodes that are matched by XPath expressions in an XML document. In an actual application I would not do it.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Take a look at this answer here, as this should give you the information you need:

[Difference between: child::node() and child::*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5394178/difference-between-childnode-and-child)

This gives the following **xsl:choose** to test all the nodes, including the document node.

```
<xsl:choose>
  <xsl:when test="count(.|/)=1">
    <xsl:text>Root</xsl:text>
  </xsl:when>
  <xsl:when test="self::*">
    <xsl:text>Element </xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="name()"/>
  </xsl:when>
  <xsl:when test="self::text()">
    <xsl:text>Text</xsl:text>
  </xsl:when>
  <xsl:when test="self::comment()">
    <xsl:text>Comment</xsl:text>
  </xsl:when>
  <xsl:when test="self::processing-instruction()">
    <xsl:text>PI</xsl:text>
  </xsl:when>
  <xsl:when test="count(.|../@*)=count(../@*)">
    <xsl:text>Attribute</xsl:text>
  </xsl:when>
</xsl:choose>
```

Comment: Good, but you missed namespace nodes.

Answer (score 7):

I highly recommend you to use the [expressions on sequence types introduced in XPath 2.0](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath20/#id-expressions-on-datatypes). For example:

```
. instance of document-node()
. instance of element()
```

Comment: as in `<xsl:when test=". instance of element()">`

Answer (score 6):

**A more precise way to determine if the node `$node` is *a* root node**:

```
not(count($node/ancestor::node()))
```

The expression in TimC's answer tests the type of the current node:

```
count(.|/)=1
```

but isn't applicable in the case when we want to determine the type of a node in a variable -- which may belong to another document -- not to the current document.

**Also, a test for a namespace node**:

```
count($node | $node/../namespace::*) = count($node/../namespace::*)
```