# XPath: get element type

Tags: xml, xpath

This is an XPath query which would print full path of every element in the file

```
for $boy in //*
return string-join(($boy/ancestor-or-self::*/name()), "::")
```

How do I get the element's type as well (I need to know primitive types foremost: `xs:integer`, `xs:string`, etc)?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14118670/check-type-of-node-in-xsl-template

Answer (score 3):

There is no function to determine an element's type. As you're using flwor expressions, I guess your XPath processor supports XPath 2.0: then you can use `instance of` to determine the type, eg.

- `"foo" instance of xs:string`
- `1 instance of xs:integer`
- `//* instance of element()*`

You could use use an [`if`/`else`-chain to determine the type](http://www.xqueryfunctions.com/xq/functx_atomic-type.html) (the example uses XQuery, in XPath you cannot define functions), but I cannot really come up with an XPath application example right now.

Answer (score 0):

Jens Erat's answer is correct as far as the XPath 2.0 standard goes.

In Saxon (You need EE for schema awareness) there's an extension function

```
saxon:type-annotation()
```

which gives you the type annotation of a value as a QName, and another

```
saxon:type
```

which gives you the type as a schema component, represented as a function item; you can get specific properties of the type (including its name) by supplying the required property name to this function. Details at

http://www.saxonica.com/documentation/#!functions/saxon

But I see this isn't quite what you asked for; if an element has been schema validated as an integer it will give the result as xs:integer, not as element(). It does what you want for atomic values, though.