# How to identify the component type using Xpath in Robot Framework

Tags: xpath, robotframework

I have an xpath like this: `.//*[@id='DirectoryNo_Field']` and I want to know how to identify if it's component is an InputText or a ComboBox?

Is it possible in robot framework?

Atention: Components doesn't have a pattern for its names.

Thanks Guys

Comment: > Is it possible in robot framework?

Is it possible with other tool/framework?

(I think not, from some SO answers, [1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21647247/xpath-get-element-type) and [2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21647247/xpath-get-element-type))

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried to find this element using chrome dev tools or the same functions in other browser?

To open dev tools in Chrome, with chrome active, simply press F12.  This should bring up the developer tools console/menu at the bottom.

Within that menu, navigate to 'Elements' if it isn't already highlighted and press (CTRL + F) this will bring up the find menu which will allow you to find by XPath.

Alternatively, if you know where the element is on the page, simply right-click it and select inspect element, this will take you to the element within the page source and therefore you'll have your answer.

Hope that helps.

*if I've misunderstood this and you only want to select an element of a specific type, why not change the XPath to only retrieve the type you're after?  i.e.

```
.//input[@id='DirectoryNo_Field']
```

Comment: I've tried your suggestion and it works.

Thank you.

Comment: which suggestion?  If it answered the question please accept the answer so others can benefit